# Most efficient way to find a "space" in an ordered list using LINQ

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, time-complexity

What I'm trying to do is something like if iterating through something like

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = items.Select(item => item.Id);
```

which is `0 1 5 7`

then I want to select `2` because that's the smallest number `i` in the range `[0, 7+1]` such that `i-1` is in the list while `i` isn't. If `0` isn't in the list, then `0` gets chosen, however.

What is the most compact, efficient, readable, fancy, and LINQiest way to do this?

Let me know if I need to give a more thorough explanation.

Comment: You need to give a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @Abion47 Basically, I'm trying to find the point of insertion in order

Comment: So you are not trying to look for `2` and seeing which index it goes in to? You just want to find the first index that has a gap?

Comment: "compact, efficient, readable, fancy, and LINQiest" --- choose one.

Comment: I've given several possible answers, but apparently this question page is getting visited by the happy little fairies that downvote with no explanation, so best of luck to you and your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the non-empty collections this might be the shortest possible implementation, it is `O(N)` though (it also assumes `Id` field you have is numeric, does not change anything though):

```
var missingIndex = list.TakeWhile((v, i) => v == i).Last() + 1;
```

How it works: it iterates over a list until the value matches its index. Then after some value does not match its index - is a gap.

**UPD**

with the help of [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563532/rob) it was fixed to handle lists that start with non-zeroes:

```
var missingIndex = list.TakeWhile((v, i) => v == i).Select(i => i + 1).LastOrDefault();
```

For *the efficient* solution you need to employ a binary search which would look better in the imperative style (see non-linq'y).

Comment: This only works if there is an element in the list with a `0` value. Otherwise, the `TakeWhile` returns an empty collection which `Last` will throw an exception on.

Comment: @Abion47 that's unfortunate! I will think for a minute or remove the answer :-(

Comment: @Abion47 `ids.TakeWhile((v, i) => v == i).Select(i => i + 1).LastOrDefault()` fixes that

Comment: @Rob nope, it would return a wrong result (`1` instead of `0` for the `1,2,3` input list)

Comment: @zerkms Can you give an example? It will behave as previously, except it returns `0` if `TakeWhile` matches nothing (ie, it doesn't start with a 0)

Comment: @Rob it the input list is `1,2,3` it should return `0`

Comment: @zerkms It returns 0 for 1,2,3 - just tested

Comment: @Rob oh, I missed that you removed the trailing `+ 1`

Comment: One other thing I'd like to mention is that this method assumes that the collection is sorted.

Comment: @Abion47 it is given, though, so not an assumption.

Comment: @zerkms The given example array just happened to be in order. There isn't anything in OP's code that would guarantee that it is.

Comment: @Abion47 it is stated by the OP explicitly, that it is ordered.

Comment: @zerkms Where was that stated? If you're referring to the comment, that merely says that he wants the index in the order, not that the list *is* ordered.

Comment: @Abion47 https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fbsdqqtafh4ocy/Screenshot%202016-11-04%2016.15.28.png?dl=0

Comment: @zerkms in situations like this I put a picture in a random post as a edit, copy the link to imgur SO generates, then cancel the edit, then post the link in the comment. Then you don't have to deal with managing the picture's source.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I like that solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

It would not be hard to write your extension method to do this.

```
    //examples
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your original example
            var items = new List<int> { 0, 1, 5, 7 };
            var gap = items.FindFirstGap();
            Console.WriteLine(gap); //shows 2

            //No gaps
            items = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
            gap = items.FindFirstGap();
            Console.WriteLine(gap); //shows 4

            //no 0
            items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            gap = items.FindFirstGap();
            Console.WriteLine(gap); //shows 0

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The below solution is `O(N)` and supports any struct datatype you can provide a function to calculate "+ 1" and "Equals" for. I made a overloads that does all of the base integer types logic for you so you don't need to specify it at the caller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static T FindFirstGap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, T> getNext, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) where T : struct
        {
            using (var enumerator = @this.GetEnumerator())
            {
                T nextItem = default(T);
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var currentItem = enumerator.Current;
                    if (!comparer.Equals(currentItem, nextItem))
                        return nextItem;
                    nextItem = getNext(currentItem);
                }
                return nextItem;
            }
        }

        public static T FindFirstGap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, T> getNext) where T : struct
        {
            return FindFirstGap(@this, getNext, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
        }

        public static int FindFirstGap(this IEnumerable<int> @this)
        {
            return FindFirstGap(@this, i => i + 1, EqualityComparer<int>.Default);
        }

        public static long FindFirstGap(this IEnumerable<long> @this)
        {
            return FindFirstGap(@this, i => i + 1, EqualityComparer<long>.Default);
        }

        public static short FindFirstGap(this IEnumerable<short> @this)
        {
            return FindFirstGap(@this, i => (short)(i + 1), EqualityComparer<short>.Default);
        }

        public static byte FindFirstGap(this IEnumerable<byte> @this)
        {
            return FindFirstGap(@this, i => (byte)(i + 1), EqualityComparer<byte>.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code the user sees is `items.FindFirstGap();` (see the `Main()` function at the bottom of the code for 3 example uses) The rest of the code can be tucked away in a library. The only thing you need to do is add overloads for `long` `short` `byte` and maybe `float` and `double` if you are feeling ambitious on writing the comparer yourself.

Comment: "The rest of the code can be tucked away in a library." --- then it would make sense to be a binary search.

Comment: @zerkms Thats what I thought at first too but a binary search won't work unless you have a target number you are searching for before you start the search. If you have a way it could be done please post it because I have no idea how you would implment it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's easy - the same way I do linearly but with binary search: you take the middle element and compare its value with it's index. If they match - you move right, otherwise you move left.

Comment: @zerkms Actually I guess if you where only working with `int`s you could do a binary search comparing `i == value[i]` and if it is not equal binarly search till you find the largest value that does. EDIT: looks like you posted the answer right as I figured it out myself.

Comment: Yep, now I see: unless there is a functional dependency between an index and a value - it's not possible to implement, agreed. From that perspective the "super-generic" implementation would have a `AreElementsSibling` predicate passed, not the equality comparer.

Comment: @zerkms That was actually in my first draft, but with that way you also still need to pass in a function to calculate the next result to solve the 2nd test case in my examples. So instead of passing in two delegates (`areElementsSibling` and `getNextValue`) I decided to go with the "get the next value and compare" route because .NET will auto generate comparers for value types and has built in comparers. I am going to update the answer with a few more overloads to help show the point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
    private static int GetGap(int[] items)
    {
        // return items.TakeWhile((v, i) => v == i).Select(i => i + 1).LastOrDefault();
        if (!items.Any()) return 0;
        if (items.First() != 0) return 0;
        int counter = 0;
        return items.ToList().LastOrDefault(x => x == counter++) + 1;
    }
```

Tests:

```
   public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 0, 1, 5, 7 }, 2).SetName("1");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },5).SetName("2");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },0).SetName("3");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 0).SetName("4");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },0).SetName("5");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 0 },1).SetName("6");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { },0).SetName("7");

        }
    }

    [TestCaseSource("TestCases")]
    public void Test(int[] items, int expected ) {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, GetGap(items));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding index of first gap,
please try this if it fits in your requirement.

```
 int[] items = new int[] { 0,1, 3, 4, 6 }; 
 var firstGap = items.Select((index, value) => new { value, index })
                     .FirstOrDefault(c => c.value == 0 ? items[c.value] != 0 : items[c.value] != items[c.value - 1] + 1).value;
```